# How can i add multiple line comments in WSDL file

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, comments, cxf

I have a WSDL file and i want to add comments to make it clearer.
Apache CXF offers the following annotations to insert **comments in one line**:
 `@WSDLDocumentation` and `@WSDLDocumentationCollection`.

My question is there a way to add **multiple line comments** in WSDL file ??

Please Help !

Comment: don't know if this works but you can try \n for new line

Answer (score 0):

Just Tried on my local. It works

Instead of "\n" use "& # 10 ;" (together)

Comment: can you give me an example ?